# R - Ratio of two columns per group

Tags: r, data.table, aggregation, lapply

What's an elegant way to calculate the ratio of two columns (NAs included) across all groups? Let's say we have this data:

```
 Name Col1 Col2
  Abe    2    3
  Abe    1    2
 Brad    2    1
 Brad    2    2
Chuck    1    1
Chuck    3    3
```

To calculate the ratio of Col:Col2 for each Name, we first add the values for each name per column before obtaining the ratio.

In this case, our answer is:

```
 Name Col1/Col2
  Abe       3/5
 Brad       4/3 
Chuck       4/4
```

Comment: Pick your favorite method [to sum by group (R-FAQ link)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1660124/903061), then divide. If you have trouble with that, please show your attempt so we can help you correct it. Otherwise I would recommend closing as duplicate.

Comment: Is there a way to close it without it negatively impacting me? I think I got the answer `aggregate(.~Name,df,Col1/Col2)`

Comment: A duplicate doesn't negatively impact you at all. It just sticks around as a pointer to help people find all the answers at the FAQ.

Comment: I wouldn't worry.  We have a guy that answers all the duplicates.

Comment: @RichScriven Oh hey Rich! Long time no see! I remember you helping me out a few... 10+ months ago!